# File checking function C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a file checking function but something seems to terrible wrong (doesn't it always). Please keep in mind I'm just starting with C++.

There is the relevant part of main();

```
int main() {


string file, pick, first, firstFirst, second, third, fourth, note;

fstream inputFile, outputfile;
bool done = false;


void display(string second);
void copy(string second, string fourth);
void create(string second);
string getFileName(ios_base::openmode mode);
do {
    stringstream choice;

    //Ask for prompt
    cout << "Enter one of the Following:\n\
quit - Quit the program\n\
Copy <f1> to <f2>\n\
display <f1>\n\
create <f1> <word to quit>\n\
Enter Option: ";

    getline(cin, pick);             //insert their response into a string
    choice << pick;                     //copy string to a stringstream
    choice >> firstFirst;       //copy each word to seperate variables

    //cin.clear();

    first.resize(firstFirst.size());
    transform(firstFirst.begin(), firstFirst.end(),       
    first.begin(),::tolower);

    if (first == "display")

    {

        second = getFileName(ios::in);      //file check & get second
        if (second == "bad")
        {
            cout << "That file does not exist";
            break;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Displaying" << second;
            cout << endl << endl;
            display(second);
        }
```

and here is my getFileName function (file checker)

```
string getFileName(ios_base::openmode mode)

{
string fileName;
fstream inputFile;

cin >> fileName;            //pull file name string off buffer

if (mode == ios::in)
{
    while (fileName.at(0) == '"')
    {
        fileName.erase(
        remove(fileName.begin(), fileName.end(), '\"'),
        fileName.end()
        );
    }

    inputFile.open(fileName, ios::in);
    {
        if (inputFile.good() != true)
        {
            inputFile.close();
            fileName = "bad";

        }
        else
        {
            inputFile.close();

        }
    }
}

else if (mode == ios::out)
{
    while (fileName.at(0) == '"')
    {
        fileName.erase(
        remove(fileName.begin(), fileName.end(), '\"'),
        fileName.end()
        );
    }

    inputFile.open(fileName, ios::in);
    {
        if (inputFile.good() != true)
        {
            inputFile.close();
            fileName = "bad";
        }
        else
        {
            inputFile.close();

        }
    }
}

else 
{

    fileName = "bad";

}

return fileName;
}
```

Thanks a million for any offered help.

Comment: What do you want to check? And what happens (error message, crash, ...)?

Comment: I want to use the function so I can check if the file already exists (if they're trying to create a new file) or if it doesn't exist (if they're trying to open a file).   Right now the function isn't firing, it will just go black.

Comment: Just add tons of `cerr << __LINE__ << endl;` to trace the flow of control

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's best to develop new functionality in isolation as much as possible. Try writing a program that tests for the existence of a file called "dummy.txt", with no user input. Once that works, encapsulate that code in a function. Once you have that in your toolbox, you can take another look at your project.

Comment: You shouldn't check for a file existence like that, because that way you'll have race conditions. Eg. if you want to create/write a file only if it doesn't exist yet, you check and then write; but what happens if some other program creates the file beteen these two things? There are already functions to check *and* open "atomcally", ie. working with the OS to prevent such race conditions. Just use them. (*Creating* such functions is not trivial at all.)

Comment: I would love to not do this function but it's part of a lot large assignment for school and the getFileName function is required as is.

Comment: string getFileName(ios base::openmode) - The parameter to the function is the open.mode of the file (e.g. ios::in or ios::out). If the user specifies ios::in then the function must require the user to enter the name of an existing file.If the user specifies ios::out then the function must require the user to enter the name of a file that does not exist.